# Testing React Native Firebase/Firestore + Typescript with jest on windows machine

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to write tests for my react native firebase/firestore methods, which are written with jest and typescript. I'm getting different kinds of errors with different approaches, which have led me to follow a ts-jest guide to set up with react native, which led me through an error saying I couldn't use imports (fixed by adding the relevant node_modules to transformIgnorePatterns in jest.config.js), and now I have the error "Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null".

I also tried setting `automock:true` in jest.config.js, but this gave me 'Cannot read TypeError: Cannot read property 'OS' of undefined', where undefined is Platform inside @react-native-firebase/app. Does this mean I cannot test these functions on a normal windows machine, and instead need to be running the tests in some ios emulator? I've just migrated from MongoDB+my own server code to using firebase directly from react native in the hopes of avoiding a separate backend for just transporting data from the DB.

In some solutions, I've seen people mocking the functions in /firestore, but I want to actually store data on the emulator running on my machine to actually see if these functions are working. Does anyone have a solution to this? There has to be a lot of people who have had the same issue, but I can't find any solutions for it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my current relevant files, tell me if you need more:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "somename",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "emulators:start:firestore": "firebase emulators:start --only firestore",
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    //Lots of other stuff here, but this is the important one
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.5",
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.20.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.4",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  }
}
```

jest.config.js (notice my transformIgnorePattern to ensure the firebase node_modules are compiled correctly):

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets');

module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  preset: 'react-native',
  transform: {
    ...tsjPreset.transform,
    '\\.js$': './node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/?!(@react-native-firebase/firestore|@firebase/testing|@react-native-firebase/app)"],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babelConfig: true,
    }
  },
  cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache',
};
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

My testfile:

```
import * as Members from '../../DBCommunications/MemberService';
import firebase, {assertSucceeds} from '@firebase/testing';

const memberId = '123';
const memberName = 'Test';
const memberImage = 'image.png';

beforeAll(() => {
    firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: 'testid', auth: {uid: 'tester', email: 'test@test.com'}})
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await Promise.all(firebase.apps().map((app: any) => app.delete()));
    await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId: 'testid'});
});

describe('Member Service', () => {
    it('Can create a member', async () => {
        const member = await Members.createMember(memberId, memberName, memberImage);
        expect(member).toBe(true);
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Members.createMember (important bits):

```
import firestore, {FirebaseFirestoreTypes} from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'
import {Member} from "../Interfaces/Member";

export const createMember = async (id: string, name: string, image: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        const member: Member = {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            image: image
        };
        firestore().collection(membersCollectionName).add(member)
            .then(() => resolve(true))
            .catch(() => reject('Could not create member'));
    })
};
```

Comment: The problem is specific to @react-native-firebase , which is third-party package. Unless it provides a way to mock RN calls in tests, you need to handle this yourself, automock is not enough because it stubs, not mocks. Something like https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26579#issuecomment-538610849 . See how the lib uses RN and try to fulfill its expectations, https://unpkg.com/browse/@react-native-firebase/app@8.2.0/lib/internal/registry/nativeModule.js Consider opening an issue in the repo but since it doesn't already handle this, I wouldn't expect a ready solution

Comment: Thank you for this answer. At least now I understand what’s not working and can start fixing the issue.